# C - Stack allocated linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

My goal with the following code was to have a user enter some integers, have those integers stored in stack allocated nodes of type `INT_NODE` and then link all those nodes together.  Finally, I wanted to iterate through the list and print out the element at each node (only the first 5 in the following code).  When I enter some numbers, however, the program prints out the first number I entered, and then the last number I entered repeated 4 times.  For example, if I enter `84 5 12 7 1 22 31[Enter]` and then press `Ctrl+D` at the beginning of the next line to simulate EOF on this Mac, I get the following output; `84 31 31 31 31`.  I can't figure out why it is doing this.

I am aware that I could allocate the nodes on the heap using `malloc()` and I have already written a function to do that.  I was just wondering if it were possible to do it using the runtime stack.

In the following code, the `INT_NODE` type is defined in the `"SortingAlgs.h"` header as the following;

```
typedef struct INT_NODE {
    int element;
    struct INT_NODE *next;
} INT_NODE;
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SortingAlgs.h"

int main(void) {

    INT_NODE head = {-999999999};
    int num;
    INT_NODE *pCurrentNode = &head;

    if (scanf("%d", &num) != EOF) {
        head.element = num;

        while (scanf("%d", &num) != EOF) {
            INT_NODE newNode;

            newNode.element = num;
            newNode.next = NULL;
            pCurrentNode->next = &newNode;
            pCurrentNode = pCurrentNode->next;
        }
    } 
    int i;
    for (pCurrentNode = &head, i = 0; i < 5;
         pCurrentNode = pCurrentNode->next, i++)

        printf("%d  ", pCurrentNode->element);

    printf("\n");

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: And who is going to allocate enough memory for this?

Comment: To do it using run-time stack you'd either need 1) a non-standard run-time allocation through `alloca` or 2) recursive functions, where each level of recursion would host a single list node. That's about it. What you have now is not viable and only leads to undefined behavior. Of course, you can simply pre-allocate a fixed number of nodes as a local array and hope it is enough for your list... But I'm sure this is not what you meant.

Comment: `INT_NODE newNode;` ： This is invalid outside the scope.

Comment: your are creating AND destroying yr node each time round that while loop. Gotta do it on the heap

Comment: Note that the only reason your printing loop stops is because of the `i < 5` term.  For a true linked list, you'd keep going until you reached a node with a null next pointer (most common case).  If you tried that, you'd most probably get `31` produced 'for ever' (until you got bored and killed your program).  That's a symptom of your troubles.

Answer (score 4):

To do it using run-time stack you could use one of the following:

1. Run-time allocation through `alloca`. This is easy: basically just replace `malloc` with `alloca` (and don't attempt to wrap `alloca` into another function). However, `alloca` is not a standard function.
2. Recursive function, where each level of recursion would host a single list node (or a fixed number of list nodes). This has some severe limitations, but technically it meets your requirement of allocating all nodes on the stack.
3. Pre-allocate a fixed number of nodes as a local array and hope it is enough for your list... But I'm sure this is not what you meant.

That's about it. What you have now is not viable and only leads to undefined behavior. Your list basically "consists" of `INT_NODE` objects whose lifetime has already ended. In practice you'll typically end up reusing the same memory location again and again effectively linking a single node to itself.

Here's an example if an implementation that keeps the whole list "on the stack" following the recursive approach. Of course, the list exists only as long as all recursive invocations are "active". This limits the applicability of this technique, but it has it uses

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct INT_NODE 
{
  int element;
  struct INT_NODE *next;
} INT_NODE;

void print_list(const INT_NODE *head)
{
  for (const INT_NODE *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    printf("%d  ", current->element);
  printf("\n");
}

void build_list(INT_NODE *head, INT_NODE *last)
{
  INT_NODE new = { 0 };

  if (scanf("%d", &new.element) != 1)
  {
    print_list(head);
    return;
  }

  if (head == NULL)
    head = &new;
  else
    last->next = &new;

  build_list(head, &new);
}

int main(void) 
{
  build_list(NULL, NULL);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a4f15a82c66d992

Comment: Oh no, the answer I was going to give the green checkmark to is gone. :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is the scope of variables.
Enter 5, program allocate memory on stack, but it will be returned.
Enter 12, allocate same memory, return it.
so finally, the head next pointer is the same memory, and the same memory next pointer is itself.

you can output more than 5. maybe you will get  84 31 31  31 31 31 31 31 .....

Comment: Please post answers only if you are sure.